# Partial fraction decomposition $\frac{1}{(x-y)^2}\frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus

I want to integrate $$\frac{1}{(x-y)^2}\frac{1}{x^2}$$ with respect to $x$.

I know that I have to apply partial fraction decomposition but which ansatz do I have to make to arrive at

$$\frac{1}{(x-y)^2}\frac{1}{x^2}=-\frac{2}{y^3(x-y)}+\frac{1}{y^2(x-y)^2}+\frac{2}{y^3x}+\frac{1}{y^2x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is the (comparatively) fast way to determine the partial fraction decomposition, using the poles of the fraction. To make the computation clearer, I'll denote  temporarily $y$ as  the constant $a$.

The decomposition has the form
$$\frac 1{x^2(x-a)^2}=\frac Ax+\frac B{x^2}+\frac C{x-a}+\frac D{(x-a)^2}.\tag 1$$
Multiplying both sides by $x^2(x-a)^2$, you obtain
$$1=Ax(x-a)^2+B(x-a)^2+Cx^2(x-a)+Dx^2.$$
Setting $x=0$ yields instantly $\;B=\dfrac1{a^2}$. Similarly, setting $x=a$ yields $D=\dfrac1{a^2}$.

To obtain the last two coefficients, multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $x$ and let $x\to\infty$: you obtain the relation $\:A+C=0$.
We need a last equation to determine $A$ & $C$. The best way seems to let $x=\frac a2$ (the arithmetic mean of the poles), which yields the relation
$$A-C=\frac 4{a^3},\quad\text{whence}\quad A=\frac 2{a^3},\enspace C=-\frac 2{a^3}.$$
*Note*:

If the fraction has a pole of higher order, it is generaly still faster to use division of polynomials by increasing degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Treat $y$ as a constant. So in the denominator we have $2$ terms  $x$ and $(x-y)$, both raised to the power $2$.

So, let $$\frac{1}{(x-y)^2x^2} = \left(\frac{a}{x}  + \frac{b}{x^2}\right) + \left(\frac{c}{x-y}+\frac{d}{(x-y)^2}\right)$$

By method of inspection, we can easily get $b$ and $d$.

$x= 0 \Rightarrow b = \frac{1}{(0-y)^2} = \frac{1}{y^2}$

$x =y \Rightarrow d = \frac{1}{y^2}$

Now you have,

$\frac{1}{(x-y)^2x^2} = \left(\frac{a}{x}  + \frac{1}{y^2x^2}\right) + \left(\frac{c}{x-y}+\frac{1}{y^2(x-y)^2}\right)$

$\Rightarrow1 = ax(x-y)^2 + c(x-y)x^2 + \frac{(x-y)^2+x^2}{y^2}$
Let us consider only coefficients of $x^2$ and $x^3$

$ (a+c) = 0 $ and $(-2ay-cy+\frac{2}{y^2}) = 0$

Using $c = -a , -ay + \frac{2}{y^2} = 0 \Rightarrow a= \frac{2}{y^3}$ and $c= -\frac{2}{y^3}$

Thus,

> $$\frac{1}{(x-y)^2x^2} = \left(\frac{2}{y^3x}  + \frac{1}{y^2x^2}\right) + \left(\frac{-2}{y^3(x-y)}+\frac{1}{y^2(x-y)^2}\right)$$

Comment: I don't quite understand how you get $b$ and $d$. What do you mean by $x\to 0$?

Comment: Put $x=0$ and $x = y$ . This is a general method to find the constant with highest power of the variable in denominator. You can verify that by first cross-multiplying and putting $x=0$. In that case, you'd be having $1=a(0) + b(y^2) + c(0) +d(0) $ so, $b = \frac{1}{y^2}$. Similarly you can find $d$.